# Crash when switch to AirPlay

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm working on app that streaming audio. I've MPVolumeView with AirPlay button. But sometimes app crashes when switch to airplay.

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x394455d0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   Foundation                      0x39f05040 +[NSObject(NSDelayedPerforming) cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:] + 336
2   MediaPlayer                     0x381d43b0 -[MPAudioDeviceController _scheduleSendDelegateAudioRoutesChanged] + 52
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3ac90346 _CFXNotificationPost + 1418
4   Foundation                      0x39f0538a -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
5   Celestial                       0x35d3c0a4 -[AVObjectRegistry safePostNotificationFromMainThreadTarget:name:userInfo:] + 92
6   Celestial                       0x35d41970 figConnection_ActiveAudioRouteDidChange_Callback + 112
7   CoreFoundation                  0x3ad0c0a2 __CFNotificationCenterAddObserver_block_invoke_0 + 122
8   CoreFoundation                  0x3ac90346 _CFXNotificationPost + 1418
9   CoreFoundation                  0x3ac91918 CFNotificationCenterPostNotification + 100
10  CoreMedia                       0x3a111c96 CMNotificationCenterPostNotification + 114
11  MediaToolbox                    0x33ccae16 playerasync_reflectSubPlayerNotification + 118
12  CoreFoundation                  0x3ad0c0a2 __CFNotificationCenterAddObserver_block_invoke_0 + 122
13  CoreFoundation                  0x3ac90346 _CFXNotificationPost + 1418
14  CoreFoundation                  0x3ac91918 CFNotificationCenterPostNotification + 100
15  CoreMedia                       0x3a111c96 CMNotificationCenterPostNotification + 114
16  MediaToolbox                    0x33ccad92 playerremote_postNotification + 554
17  MediaToolbox                    0x33cccd28 playerremote_postNotificationWithPayload + 84
18  MediaToolbox                    0x33cca2ce FigPlayerRemoteCallbacksServer_SendNotifyPing + 370
19  MediaToolbox                    0x33cca14e _XSendNotifyPing + 66
20  MediaToolbox                    0x33cc74de figmoviecallbacks_server + 90
21  MediaToolbox                    0x33cc7468 fpr_ClientPortCallBack + 176
22  CoreFoundation                  0x3ad09888 __CFMachPortPerform + 116
23  CoreFoundation                  0x3ad143e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
24  CoreFoundation                  0x3ad14386 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
25  CoreFoundation                  0x3ad1320a __CFRunLoopRun + 1378
26  CoreFoundation                  0x3ac86238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
27  CoreFoundation                  0x3ac860c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
28  GraphicsServices                0x36f8c336 GSEventRunModal + 70
29  UIKit                           0x34a9328c UIApplicationMain + 1116
30  RogApp                          0x0006a0ba main (main.m:17)
31  RogApp                          0x0006a034 start + 36
```

I've enabled zombie objects and after crash I see message like this:

```
[MPAudioDeviceController performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:inModes:] message sent to deallocated instance
```

This is private class. How can I fix this bug?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I am getting essentially the same crash reports from the field with an app. I did not know what it was related to, but now I can at least explore switching to AirPlay to drive it.